# My flatlist doesn't show up the new message when someone was send. React-Native

Tags: react-native, signalr

When i got a text message from another and i have to scroll little up to show a new message. That work different way when i send message, it's just show without scroll

RN 0.59, SignalR

How i got a message

```js
 componentDidMount() {
    this._isMounted = true;

    this.refreshDataFromServer();

    hub.on("message", (id, name, msg, img, uId) => {
        if (this._isMounted) {
            if (id !== null) {
                //let mess = '{"Name":"' + name + '","Message":"' + msg + '","Image":"' + img + '"}';
                let mess = '{"Id":"' + id + '","Name":"' + name + '","Message":"' + msg + '"}';

                var obj = JSON.parse(mess.toString());
                this.state.data.push(obj);

               
            }
        }
    });
    hub.on("Loading", () => { }
    );
    hub.on("doneLoad", () => { }
    );
}
```

My flatlist

```js
render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                 <FlatList
                    data={this.state.data}
                    removeClippedSubviews={false} 
                    extraData={this.state.data}
                    ref={(ref) => { this.flatListRef = ref; }}
                    onContentSizeChange={()=> this.flatListRef.scrollToEnd()}
                    renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
                        return (
                            <FlatListItem item={item} index={index} navigation={this.props.navigation}>

                            </FlatListItem>);
                    }}
                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => String(index)}
                    refreshControl={
                        <RefreshControl
                            refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
                            onRefresh={this.onRefresh}
                        />}
                />
                <View style={styles.footer}>
                    <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
                        <TextInput style={styles.inputs}
                            multiline = {true}
                            ref={input => { this.textInput = input }}
                            placeholder="Write a message..."
                            underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
                            onChangeText={(text) => this.updateValue(text, 'sendMessage')}>
                        </TextInput>    
                    </View>

                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btnSend}
                        onPress={this.sendMessage}>
                        <Image source={{ uri: "https://png.icons8.com/small/75/ffffff/filled-sent.png" }} style={styles.iconSend} />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
```

I'm a newbie in RN so i don't really know how lifecycle in RN work. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't set value directly to state like `this.state.data.push(obj)`

It won't trigger render.Instead, you need to use [setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly)

```
this.setState({
     data: this.state.data.concat(obj)
})
```

Comment: I was about to post the same thing as it now, but it was different before your "edit". Ninja edit is a lingo for post being edited without trace like ninja not being seen.